# In App Purchases returns error

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes

I create IAP with that tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

And it works ok, but the I updated IAP to new items(has passed ~ 2 weeks) and it did not working. I get list of IAP on the simulator, but not on the device.

I have this error from

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

 Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

Why this can happens ?

Comment: Stupid question but does the device have internet access? I have to ask

Comment: Do you add new items inside this array ? NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                      @"com.Company.ProductName.fullversion",
                                      nil];

Comment: @Beto, yes with code all ok, 3 times I checked it. Maybe it iTunes, how can I get it?

Comment: You must check inside itunesconnect the names of each inapp product just if have a typo error.